# How can I find what vampire weaknesses are real without putting myself in danger?

Tags: internal-consistency, vampires

I live in [the world of darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Darkness). I'm a simple human. I discovered that vampires exist. They killed my girlfriend in front of me. I ran away. Now I want to look for them, find them, and kill them.

But I'm facing a big problem. I'm weak. I'm just a normal guy who hates sports and plays video games. I know a lot from books that can teach me what the  weaknesses of vampires are, but they contradict each other on some points.

How can I find what vampire weaknesses are real without putting myself in (too much) danger?

Comment: Easy: don't escalate: start with beheading and immolation. Most things are vulnerable to those, so they work just great on non-vampires too, in case you've got your parahumans mixed up. Remember, if violence _isn't_ your last resort, then you probably failed to resort to enough of it.

Comment: Hire people to find out for you ;-)

Comment: Now that you know Vampires exist, you need to change your habits: Fewer video games, more exercise and sport, less alone time and more friends, more (sober) company at night (byproduct: more casual sex!), more carrying around wooden stakes. As to discovering what works...well, you've has a science class or two, and some physics. Start rigging remote-control deathtraps. Re-watch *Home Alone* for some excellent inspiration.

Comment: ...of course, none of that will help. The vampires will frame you for the death of your girlfriend. Nobody will listen to your seemingly-insane warnings. The corrupt judge will sentence you to the secretly-vampire-run asylum, and they will gleefully feed upon you every night. You will live to a ripe old age, forgotten by the outside, bound and tortured and broken, giving life and pleasure to the growing evil.

Comment: ...which World of Darkness? Old? New? New 2.0? Because for each there is at least one supplement that deals with your setup. In the new World of Darkness there is an entire gameline - *Hunter: the Vigil* and about a third of it deals with your question. Tier 1 hunters are simple humans that *just* discovered vampires (and other supernaturals) exist and want to stop them but aren't sure how. Tier 2 hunters have some knowledge and have assembled in "clubs" and tier 3 hunters are part of massive conspiracies on-par in terms of secrecy with vampires themselves.

Comment: @VLAZ The 20 anniversary edition one. And I know for the book, but they don't really describe how to play an hunter (or a group of hunter) with low physicals stats, like a (group of) nerd(s). That, more or less, why I'm here.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like this answer is fishing for something of a scientific answer like lab research; however many genres of vampire fiction also seem to denote some inter-party conflicts. I would recommend finding a vampire on the "left" side of vampirism (only drinks animal blood or blood donations or something, maybe they have a reason for vengeance on other vampires them selves).

In this sense teaming up would allow you first hand knowledge, i.e. just ask them "What about sunlight?", etc.

Assuming your scope of vengeance is specifically on those that wronged you this should work just fine.

Comment: "*I would recommend finding a vampire*" how? Vampires tend to be very secretive. The usual way to even find they exist is to either be a victim or know a victim. Also, to survive enough to even be able to look into vampires. One that doesn't feed from humans will be even *harder* to find than normal. Convincing the vampire to share its knowledge is a *whole* different matter altogether. Let me illustrate this - if I were to come up to you and ask "Hey buddy, what's the best way to kill you? Just asking" I'm pretty sure you're not going to be thrilled. No matter how I phrase it.

Comment: "Be a victim or know one" ok check that off, from the OP's question. Point is there can be a narrative way to do this, maybe he follows them, sees a few buildings they go to. Maybe just seeing/knowing vampires exist sort of opens your eyes; that one neighbor in your apartment that always works nights? Hmmm.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm just a normal guy that hate sport and play video games.

I guess this rules out capturing one of them and have him/her "volunteer" to be your guinea pig.

What can you do?

Well, some experiments that do not require your physical prowess can be set up:

- find a path where they often walk through. Block it with two obstacles of the same size, but one topped with the substance you want to test, the other not. Note which one is moved.

In this way you can test

- garlic
- silver
- crosses
- holy water

just to cite the few I have heard being effective against vampires.

Comment: Hardly an exhaustive method. Let's assume there is some alleyway or something that vampires go through a lot. You dangle, say, crosses and want to see if they still go through. You write down the result whatever it is. You are not likely to be able to repeat that, as vampires will likely avoid that way from now on. You have to do your whole research again to find another path (if any) to repeat the experiment with, say, garlic. It's unrealistic you'd be able to test enough substances before vampires take an even further issue with being stalked.

Answer (score 2):

You live in the world of darkness, so you are not alone in your quest for vengeance.
Find an Imbued/Hunter, or an agent from one of the government agencies which secretly handle monsters.  They will be able to tell you which legends are true and which ones will get you killed.

The best way to find someone to help you is to get yourself hidden someplace safe and then violate the Masquerade.  Out the existence of vampires in a public forum, then wait for an online reply.  Then keep adding more details to your post until enough respondents have gathered that at least one of them will be legit.  Sure most of those who respond to you will be vampires, minions or traitors to humanity, but if you are very lucky, there will be a friend as well.  Then set up a very, very public meeting place with many entry/exit options and roll the dice.  If there is a friend among the respondents, they will be prepared to protect you from all the others who show up.  If not, bring your preferred suicide device so that your death can be swift and permanent.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an experiment that most easily done with a willing volunteer. Not you, of course. You need to be a human for that sweet, sweet vengeance because becoming a regenerating, flying creature of the night with enhanced speed, strength, and teeth is really just out of the question. (Because it's so much more satisfying to see the look on their smug superior vampire face when they see they got killed by a puny human, that's why!)

So your best option is to carefully (very carefully!) keep track of these things and try and guess their eating habits. Not to stop them, of course, but because their definitely have to be vampires which are sloppy eaters, and instead of leaving behind a corpse, leave behind a almost-dead vampire. All you have to do is find one of these poor unfortunate souls and rescue them, taking them into your lair. Explain to them that their life has been ruined by vampires, do your best to really get their revenge juices flowing like yours, and then have them undertake a battery of experiments (not designed to be *lethal*, of course) to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: In the World of Darkness they'd leave a almost dead human behind, no accidental embraces.

Comment: What @RobertMartinu said. But even if we leave the WoD setting aside - you don't *know* how vampires are created. The whole plan hinges on knowledge you don't have and even then a whole set of rather lucky guesses and accidents. You have to find 1. multiple vampires 2. find "sloppy eaters". 3. monitor them 4. without being noticed 5. hope they don't just kill their victim from feeding 6. hope they don't just kill their victim *if* (and that's a big if) the victim gets accidentally turned into a vampire 7. hope the victim cooperates. That's *a lot* of things that can go wrong.